# Start alarmManager at precise time even if the app is not running

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm writing an Android app that has a list of deadlines and I want to notify to user, when the time has come, that one of them is expired at the exact deadline's date, even if the app is not running. 
I use an AlarmManager, a custom BroadcastReceiver and a custom Services class, but even if I give the exact time to the alarm it always fire notification only when I run the app.
This is where I set the alarm:

```
public static void setAlarm( String string){
          AlarmManager alarms =(AlarmManager)Utility.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ALARM_INTENT_FILTER);
    intent.putExtra("content",string);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Utility.getContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

This is the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationServices.class);
        service1.putExtra("content",intent.getStringExtra("content"));
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

This is the services class:

```
public class NotificationServices extends Service
    {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {return null;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {super.onCreate();}

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = Utility.jsonObjectFromString(intent.getStringExtra("content"));
        DeadLinesList deadlinesList = new DeadLinesList(jsonObject);
        Date currentdate = Utility.removeTime(new Date());

        String message = "";
        for (DeadLine deadline : deadlineList.getDeadline()){
            if (deadline.getDateDeadline()!= null && Utility.removeTime(deadline.getDateDeadline()).compareTo(currentdate) == 0){
                message += deadline.getDeadlineName()+"\n";
            }

        }
        if (message.length()>0){
            NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Utility.getContext());

                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Utility.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Utility.getContext(),0, newIntent, 0);

                    b.setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                            .setContentTitle("Message")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(message))
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).build();

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) Utility.getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {super.onDestroy();}

}
```

This is the manifest where I register the services and the receiver:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true">

    <receiver android:name=".Notifications.NotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ALARM_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Notifications.NotificationServices"
        android:enabled="true">
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Where is the error? Why notification are fired only when I open app, and not at the precise time of the day, or when app is not running?

Answer (score 1):

From the API of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 14... I used all type of alarm manager's method...but the result is all the same.